# Render datepicker in div

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've searched for few hours but with no result.
I use [Angular Date Range Picker](https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker) in dropdown.
How can i make it render in specific place rather than cover what's under it?
Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s86n1nhe/)
And code:

```
<input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth"/>

$(function () {
    $("#dateofbirth").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: what about this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-dialog @pos?

Comment: How am i supposed to use it with https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker ?

Comment: your example has nothing to do with angular date range picker, plus I don't understand what exactly you want. You ask how to render that datepicker, not daterangePicker.

Comment: Actually daterangePicker consists of two datepickers. I want these datepickers to move everything what is under it in dropdown down, so that they don't cover anything but rather push it down.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the CSS so that the box expands but this worked for me. Find the position of the bottom of the calendar and then apply the value to the CSS property of `bottom`.

```
<span style="display:none;">
    <div id="mybox">
        <br/> <br/> 
        <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth"/>
        <p class="textbox">
        I want this text to be pushed down when datepicker opens
        </p>
        <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/>
   </div>
</span>
```

---

```
$(function () {
    $("#dateofbirth").datepicker();
    $("#dateofbirth").on('click', function(){

        var $this = $(this);
      var calendarbtm =  $("#ui-datepicker-div").position().top + $this.outerHeight(true);

      $('.textbox').css({'top': calendarbtm});

    })
});
```

---

```
.textbox {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a step forward. But not exactly what i wanted to achieve, because the datepicker goes out of the dropdown. Is there any way to make the datepicker be entirely in this dropdown? In this jsfiddle example scrollbar should appear in a dropdown.

Comment: Out of the drop down?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/djdbgznd/  Text is pushed down but the datepicker is still out of the dropdown. When you scroll down it will start above dropdown and when scroll up it will end beneath dropdown. I want it to be entire in the dropdown.